# XML Schema complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

Есть XML код

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A>
  <B C="1234">d</B> 
  <B C="4211">b</B> 
  <B C="0312">b</B> 
  <B C="1543">d</B> 
  <B C="2345">b</B> 
  <D C="1233">d</D>
  <D C="4321">b</D>
</A>
```

И к нему есть схема

```xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:attribute name="C">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:totalDigits value="4" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="C" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="D" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="C" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Затем, есть кусок схемы, который надо добавить к основной части:

```xsd
<xs:element name="elementName">
  <!— Parent name —>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="E" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="F" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Как это правильно сделать?
В ComplexType extension и choice по синтаксису ставить вместе нельзя. Соответственно добавить в уже существующий элемент не получится. Если выносить отдельно, то непонятно как сделать reference. Если выносить отдельно, то в дереве они отображаются как дополнительные элементы(что в общем-то логично, но не верно). Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я не так понял вопрос, но вроде как желаемого можно достичь, добавив атрибут `maxOccurs="unbounded"` к элементу `choice`. Что-то вроде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:attribute name="C">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>

  <xs:complexType name="hex">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute ref="C" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="parent">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">

        <xs:element name="A" type="hex" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="B" type="hex" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="C" type="hex" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="D" type="hex" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="E" type="hex" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="F" type="hex" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

После чего можно указывать элементы A, B, C, D, E, F в любом порядке. Типа такого:

```
<parent>
  <F C="1111">f</F>
  <B C="1234">d</B>
  <B C="4211">b</B>
  <B C="0312">b</B>
  <E C="1543">d</E>
  <B C="2345">b</B>
  <D C="1233">d</D>
  <D C="4321">b</D>
  <A C="5555">a</A>
</parent>
```